# How can i get the part that i want only from my Json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

My current `Json` is shared bellow, it is the response of my `request.get` in `node.js`, it is in `body`, what i want is only a part of that `json` for further processing also shared bellow:

```
{
  "query": "THIS IS MY JSON",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "INTENT",
    "score": 0.9796973
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "INTENT",
      "score": 0.9796973
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.0332397744
    },
    {
      "intent": "ANOTHER INTENT",
      "score": 0.0205348358
    },
    {
      "intent": "YET ANOTHER INTENT",
      "score": 0.0141741727
    },
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "FIRST ENTITY",
      "type": "FIRST TYPE ENTITY",
      "startIndex": 38,
      "endIndex": 47,
      "score": 0.5666461
    },
    {
      "entity": "SECOND ENTITY",
      "type": "SECOND TYPE ENTITY",
      "startIndex": 20,
      "endIndex": 32,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2017-12-14T04",
            "type": "datetime",
            "value": "2017-12-14 04:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the object **entities**.

Answer (score 0):

You just navigate your JSON as you would any JavaScript object. Inside a document like:

```
{
  "x": "y"
}
```

Then you can access the `y` value with `json.x`. In your case it's probably just:

```
json.entities
```

Where `json` is the variable representing your decoded JSON value. If it's just a string, `JSON.parse` gets the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use HTTP GET method:

```
function httpGetAsync(jsonPathOrUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", jsonPathOrUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

 function callback(response){
     if(response.entities) return response.entities;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the body which is a JSON String to Javascript Object first. 

You can try below code:

```
let json = JSON.parse(body);
let entities = json.entities
```